# How to find 4 consecutive "1" in an array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, count

I have an array that forms a matrix which looks like this (the matrix represents a piece of land):

```
  1  1  8  4  1  1
  7  1  2  6  1  8
  7  1  2  4  1  4
  7  1  6  2  1  8
  0  0  3  3  6  6
```

I need to find all vertical consecutive numbers in that array that are 1 and tell me the coordinates (coordinates as in number of `arr[4][1]`) of the first `1` in that consecutive line. I'm stuck, if someone can tell me what to add to the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int length = 5, width = 6;

int main() {
    int arr[5][6] = { { 1,  1,  8,  4,  1,  1 },
                      { 7,  1,  2,  6,  1,  8 },
                      { 7,  1,  2,  4 , 1,  4 },
                      { 7,  1,  6,  2,  1,  8 },
                      { 0,  0,  3,  3,  6,  6 },
                    };
    int count = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
        for (int j = width; j > 0; j--) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
                count++;
                printf("suitable jumps: %d %d\n", i ,j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the output for the sample input in your code?

Comment: Suggestion: See if you can solve it for the one dimensional case, and once you are sure you have that working then try to generalise it to the two dimensional case you want

Comment: Swap the loop nesting order – you need to examine column-by-column, not row-by-row. But it is unclear how `arr[2][4]` is a solution of your problem case. When you have a match, increment `count`, if you don't, set it to `1` but it needs to be initialised for each inner loop anyway.

Comment: IMO the answer is [0][1] and [0][4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the task

```
#define length 5 
#define width 6
#define NCONS 4
#define NEEDLE 1



int main(void)
{
    int arr[length][width] =  
    {{1,  1,  8,  4,  1,  1},
     {7,  1,  2,  6,  1,  8},
     {7,  1,  2,  4 , 1,  4},
     {7,  1,  6,  2,  1,  8},
     {0,  0,  3,  3,  6,  6},
    };
   int sum;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= length - NCONS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(int next = 0; next < NCONS; next++)  sum+= arr[i + next][j];

            if(sum == NEEDLE * NCONS)
            {
                printf("%d consecutive vertical %d found at: [%d][%d]\n",NCONS, NEEDLE,  i ,j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KhEGo1rKj